# Concat lots of .csv files but name them w/ filenames

Tags: python, macos, csv, pandas

I am using Pandas library to concat >200 csv files *horizontally* into a mega csv file as outlined below. Each csv is the exact same format and has no headers, with multiple columns of data, and the code listed works well for this.

However, I would like to add a header row across the top of each csv (in the mega-file), and have it named according to the filename of where the respective data came from. Each csv is named with a timestamp (yyyymmdd-hhmmss.csv) when it is created. Is this possible?

```
#I pinched the base of this code from stack overflow already
import pandas as pd
import glob

bigdata = pd.DataFrame()

dfs = []
for f in glob.glob("*.csv"): #for all csv files in pwd
    #add parameters to read_csv
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None) #create dataframe for reading current csv

dfs.append(df) #appends current csv to final DF
bigdata = pd. concat(dfs, ignore_index=True, axis=1)

bigdata.to_csv('bigdata.csv', index=None, header=None)
```

Using Python 2.7.xx, Pandas & osx

Comment: you're confusing `header` with columns here, you would only be able to rename a single column using the filename, otherwise you'd need to add a multiindex column but for the sake of display convenience, it'll make data selection unnecessarily annoying

Comment: Ok cool, so would I rename a column with the filename?